# How to empty caches when a new version is deployed?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, caching, heroku

I'm using Angularjs framework and I'm updating the application frequently. But most of the time my clients are complaining about the issue I already fixed. I think there is a caching problem in my application. I searched for this issue and couldn't find proper example to fix it. Can anyone explain how to empty/clear caches after a new version of code is deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a grunt library which adds timestamp to js files and reloads them if it changed.

https://github.com/shakyShane/grunt-cache-breaker

Answer (score 0):

More information about your server side system would help. 
But a very common cache busting technique is appending a version no in your javascript includes.

```
 <script src="http://www.example.com/example.js?v=1">
```

Now whenever your javascript changes change the version no. 
Either manually or automate your build to replace this version with something like a build no.

Now as browser will see a new url it will not use the previously cached version.